# auto-update files are deleted after auto-update

Tags: node.js, electron, nsis, electron-builder

Hello everyone I build the installer with nsis ia32 arch, I use sqlite3 and everything works fine until the update is downloaded since it replaces all the files in the installation folder.
Then my database file is deleted, how can I prevent my database file from being deleted with the new versions?

Here I initialize my connection

```
export default class Connection {
    private connection;
    public initConnection(isTest) {
        this.connection = new (sqlite3.verbose()).Database('filename.db');
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here my build config

```
"build": {
    "win": {
      "target": [{
         "target": "nsis",
         "arch": ["ia32"]
     }],
     "icon": "src/assets/images/icons/icon256.ico",
     "publisherName": "spaces"
 },
 "publish": {
     "provider": "spaces",
     "name": "<space-name>",
     "region": "nyc3"
  }
}
```

electron-builder v19.33.0
electron-updater v2.10.1

thanks o/

Comment: put some code so we can check and help you.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error what happens is that when I created the connection with sqlite3 with the relative path inside the folder where the program is installed and that is not right because when the program is updated it replaces all the content in that folder so there is do i reference the path  [app.getPath ('userData')](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname)

Comment: You solved it your self.Congo.